# Can't apply Material to Part of Model

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm pretty new to Blender, and I've been following a tutorial to model a character.

I'm currently trying to color it, and I've set up UV mapping and joined all of the objects together, switched to blender render, set shading to GLSL, changed the viewport shading to texture, created a new material and set the link for the material from data to object, but when I try to apply a material to the whole object, part of the model remains unchanged.

Was there something that I forgot to do? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you are talking about that yellow part of the mesh, then it's most likely an incompatible material. A Cycles material is not compatible with Blender Internal and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to switch to Cycles Render. If you don't you may not be able to see some stuff you have done.
2. Switch the viewport shading not to Texture but to Material that way you can see the stuff you have done.
3. In Edit Mode select what/where you want to color using different kinds of selecting (either use the looping methods (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>and hold and drag, or hold <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> hold and drag) or select manually by <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> clicking and holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>), then create a Material and click *assign*.

Make sure you name the Materials so you can tell them apart later.

Comment: Please... don't do that. **Post only images that have something to do with the question**. Also, please improve your answer by putting structure into it. Use paragraphs to avoid tl;dr.

Comment: Alright, this is my first time answering a question posted by someone else. Sorry.